# Identify this T-shaped part

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, technic

Seems to be used for making differential gearboxes, cars, and GBCs.

[image: part image]

Comment: It's used for many things!  It's great at joining beams together at perpendicular angles.  When disassembling technic sets, these are often the most challenging to get through.

Comment: It's difficult to find a modern technic set that does NOT contain this element, it's ubiquitous...

Comment: Vic, welcome to Bricks.SE. Does your piece take an axle or a pin in the direction we can't see from the angle of the picture?

Comment: Thank you. It takes a pin

Answer (score 9):

Here you have the Bricklink link to the part: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=63869#T=C

[image]

it is named Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Perpendicular Triple on BrickLink. The ldraw/bricklin item id is 63869. The Lego design id is either 63869 or 42191, indicating that there have been at least two moulds.